# How to execute .sh files one after another with php

Tags: php, sh

I need to run a series of six .sh files on the server.

An example of one of the .sh files:

```
wget ftp://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@ftp.interhome.com/accommodation.xml.zip
unzip accommodation.xml.zip
php accommodation.php
rm -rf accommodation.xml.zip
rm -rf accommodation.xml
```

I tried running the following from a php file:

```
echo shell_exec('sh accomodation.sh');
```

Which was stupid because the file appears to execute repeatedly and I think I've just taken down the server. Whoops.

I've inherited this site and have never used .sh files before. I'm also a php novice.

How would I go about running the files only once and then running the next?

Many thanks

Comment: Try adding #!/bin/bash on top of the .sh file, make it executable - chmod +x accomodation.sh and then try with passthru('/path/to/accomodation.sh'); It should be working fine. Other thing you can consider is if the script is not needed to execute directly after a user input on the web server you can put the whole thing in a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do all this from within PHP, you do not need any shell-script.

```
/* get the file via ftp */
// connect to server
$ftp = ftp_connect('ftp.interhome.com');
// login
$login = ftp_login($ftp,"username","password");
// download file to tmp.zip
$file = ftp_get($ftp, 'tmp.zip', 'accommodation.xml.zip', FTP_BINARY);
// disconnect from server
ftp_close($ftp);

/* unzip the file */
// new zip-instance
$zip = new ZipArchive;
// open downloaded file
$res = $zip->open(’tmp.zip’);
// check if file is readable
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract to current directory
  $zip->extractTo(’./’);
  // close zip-file
  $zip->close();
}

/* your code from accommodation.php goes here */

// delete files
unlink('tmp.zip');
unlink('accommodation.xml');
```

voila